# A struct that has a strange return type

Tags: c++

Could you help me with this problem

```
struct b {
    Something bSomething;
    const Something & MySomething() const {
         return bSomething;
    }
};
```

I want to know why the method return type is const Something& 
I think it might just be simply Something as in

```
 Something MySomething() const {
         return bSomething;
    }
```

and

```
Something MySomething()  {
             return bSomething;
        }
```

Thank you

Comment: How are your two cases different?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot return a non-constant reference to a member in a constant function. The usual two overloads for direct member accessors are like this:

```
const Foo & foo() const { return m_foo; }
      Foo & foo()       { return m_foo; }
```

Inside a constant function, the type of `this` is `const T *` (where `T` is your class). Thinking of your class as a dumb C struct for a minute, you are returning `*this->m_foo`, but that's constant when `this` is a pointer-to-constant, so you cannot make a non-constant reference to that.

Returning by value is fine because you invoke the *copy constructor* of `Foo`, which has signature `Foo(const Foo&)` -- so it can copy from constant references:

```
Foo copy_foo() const { return m_foo; }  // calls Foo(*this->m_foo)
```

Answer (score 2):

That mean that the value returned is not editable (first *const*) **and** that calling this method will not alter the struct instance in any way (second *const*)

The second const is very interesting because you can use it on const values too.
If you have a situation where a method return a *const mytype&*, you can call methods only if they are declared *const* (at the end like the one before). Otherwise you aren't allowed to do that.

If you leave out the first *const*, you will have a value that is editable. However because you are returning it through a const method (something that doesn't alter the struct, but returning a non-const value that is inside the class **is** a possibility to change the *value* of the instance), it's not valid a valid operation

Comment: Thanks, but now what if I leave out the const keyword  Something & MySomething() {
         return bSomething;

Comment: @Dalton: The question of whether your member functions should be const or not is related to how you *use* your class. If your class is `T` and you have `const T x;` or `const T & y = z;`, then you can only invoke const member functions on `x` and `y`, so it's very important to provide the precise amount of const-correctness in your code to allow for maximum usability. (Many algorithms take const references for instance.)